# Xamarin iOS Watch can't install on watch

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, watchkit

I have an iPhone app on Xamarin working. I just added a Watch extension project. I can deploy the app on my iPhone device, but when I try to install it on my Watch device, it fails when it reaches near 100% (icon visible with progress), and then uninstalls. There is no error message either. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your provisioning profile include the watch device? Please see:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/watch/deployment/device/

> Testing iOS apps on a real iPhone or iPad has always required the device to be registered on the Dev Center...
>
> Watches are no different - you now need to add your Apple Watch device before deploying apps to it. Find the watch's UDID using Xcode (Windows > Devices list)...
>
> When you know the Watch's UDID, add it to the device list in the Dev Center:...
>
> Once the Watch device has been added, ensure it is selected in any new or existing development or ad-hoc provisioning profiles you create:

So once you add your watch to the Devices in your Apple iOS Portal, you will have to regenerate and re-download your provisioning profile after including the watch device in the profile.

Comment: I added my watch's UDID to the device list (I can confirm that I entered it correctly because it recognized it as a watch), regenerated and re-downloaded the provisioning profile, and then rebooted my watch, phone and Mac, and still have the same problem...

Comment: I just tried it again, and it was the provisioning profile as you said. Best to double-check it as it can be tricky sometimes.